# How do you group cycles?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, combinatorics, gathering

I want to define a function that takes a list of pairs as input and groups cycles, e.g. `{{a1,a2},{b1,b2},{a2,a3},{c1,c2},{a3,a1},{b2,b1}}` becomes `{{a1,a2,a3,a1},{b1,b2,b1},{c1,c2}}`.

I'm wondering if there is an obvious function for doing this which can simply be `/@` to the list. As far as I can tell, `Cycles` does nothing to a list of this type. Is the only way to look at individual characters and manually group items?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

In your example, there is no c2->c1 (or {c2, c1}) pair, so I don't think c1->c2 is a cycle. At any rate, one idea is to use `FindCycle`:

```
pairs={{a1,a2},{b1,b2},{a2,a3},{c1,c2},{a3,a1},{b2,b1}};
FindCycle[Rule@@@pairs,Length@pairs,All]
```

> {{b1[DirectedEdge]b2,b2[DirectedEdge]b1},{a1[DirectedEdge]a2,a2[DirectedEdge]a3,a3[DirectedEdge]a1}}

If you do include `{c2, c1}`, then you have a permutation, and you can use `FindPermutation`:

```
pairs={{a1,a2},{b1,b2},{a2,a3},{c1,c2},{a3,a1},{b2,b1},{c2,c1}};
cycles = FindPermutation[pairs[[All,2]], pairs[[All,1]]]
```

> Cycles[{{1,3,5},{2,6},{4,7}}]

Which produces the cycles:

```
pairs[[#, 1]]& /@ cycles[[1]]
```

> {{a1,a2,a3},{b1,b2},{c1,c2}}